# JQuery addClass() and removeClass() synchronisation

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following table:

```
<table>
<tr class="change"><td>Click to change</td></tr>

<tbody id="p1" class="now">
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="p2" class="next">
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id="p3" class="previous">
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to hide tbody with class "now" and display the one with class "next" when I'll click the change row.

My Jquery (computes only now and next):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.change').click(function(){

    $('.now').hide('slow', function(){
        $('.next').show('slow', function(){     


        $('#p1').removeClass('recent');
        $('#p2').removeClass('next');

        $('#p1').addClass('next');
        $('#p2').addClass('recent'); 

        });
    });

});
```

});

I see I'm doing it wrong, So i want to ask you, how to nicely synchronize it in a way, that when I click on "change" my "now" tbody becomes "previous", "next" becomes "now" and "previous" becomes next?

Comment: perhaps jQuery's .toggleClass() helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.change').click(function(){
    var now = $('.now');
    var next = $('.next');
    var previous = $('.previous');
    now.hide('slow', function(){
        next.show('slow');
        previous.removeClass('previous').addClass('next');             
        now.removeClass('now').addClass('previous');
        next.removeClass('next').addClass('now');
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97L2s/1/)

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.change').click(function () {
        $('.now').hide('slow', function () {
            $('.next').show('slow', function () {
                $prev = $('.previous');
                $now = $('.now');
                $next = $('.next');
                $prev.removeClass('previous').addClass('next');             
                $now.removeClass('now').addClass('previous');
                $next.removeClass('next').addClass('now');

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're removing the 'previous' class you just added. Change it to store the results of all three selectors, then perform the `removeClass` on those arrays.

Comment: @Codesleuth, Thanks, I was overlooking that. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.change').click(function() {
    $('.now').attr('class', 'previous');
    $('.next').attr('class', 'now');
    $('.previous').attr('class', 'next');
});
```

Comment: So `.now` becomes `.previous`, then becomes `.next` right afterwards? I don't think this is what the questioner has in mind...

Comment: This has the same problem as Joy's answer as commented by Codesleuth. Additionally in a more general case you run the risk of removing other classes if the elements had them which is why add/remove class is generally better than setting the attribute directly. Not an issue with the HTML given but something to bear in mind.

Comment: "when I click on "change" my "now" tbody becomes "previous", "next" becomes "now" and "previous" becomes next?". It goes on in a circle, I think this is what he wanted :P